# How to import data from excel file to oracle database by using oracle forms

Tags: excel, oracle, oracleforms

I want to import data of excel file to oracle database by using oracle forms 10g . 
 I try to use WebUtil but it is so slow.

 Can any one help me to find another way?

 Big Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to get the file on the database server.
If the file is on the client side, you can do this by using a shared drive between your application server and db server and then transfer the file using webutil.

When the file is on the db server read the file using an external table.
See this [link](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14215/et_concepts.htm) for more information on external tables

Comment: File on EndUser Machine, so i can't do that

Comment: Like I said, use webutil to transfer it to the application server then